# are extensions of flat connections flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connections

Let $U$ be a smooth complex variety and $X$ a compactification by a normal crossings divisor $D$. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $U$ (i.e. locally free $\mathcal{O}_U$-module), together with a connection $\nabla: E \to E \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_U} \Omega^1_U$. Assume that:

(1) $\nabla$ is flat

(2) $(E, \nabla)$ has regular singularities, meaning that it can be extended to a connection $\nabla_X: E_X \to E_X \otimes \Omega^1_X(log D)$ with logarithmic poles.

Is $(E_X, \nabla_X)$ flat?

Comment: If by "flat" you mean that $\nabla_X^2=0$, then yes. The curvature is locally a matrix of (log) $1$-forms, so if it vanishes on $U$ it vanishes on $X$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Thanks!